# Listview grouping(not based on specific properties) and without code behind WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm still a newbie so take it easy on me please :p
I have three ObservableCollections of Type 
            `Coll1 = new ObservableCollection<Type>();
            Coll2 = new ObservableCollection<Type>();
            Coll3 = new ObservableCollection<Type>();`

I want to combine all of them in a ListView and i want to group the items based on their origin ( coming from Coll1, Coll2 or Coll3)
I read some articles but all i've found are the ones grouping items based on specific properties like [this one](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/). I don't know if this is possible or not?
but i really need a solution for this problem or maybe an other suggestion.
I will be thankful for any help i get!
the structure of my listview is something **like** this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here (It works like charm ):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/812ed260-e113-4a8b-9322-226ed56ac90c/grouping-of-items-in-listview-wpf?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required

regards

Comment: thx for the response but this example is grouping based on the DateTime property of ClassA objects. i don't have a property for each item that's my problem actually.